# How to ignore a folder from beautiful URL using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am developing a website, assuming example.com and a blog located at example.com/blog.
The website language is PHP (I designed and programmed it by myself), and I used wordpress as the blog.

I tried to use beautiful URL in main part of the website to convert example.com/services.php to example.com/services by means of this code in htaccess:

```
# BEAUTIFUL URL
RewriteBase /
DirectorySlash Off
# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]
# rewrite /dir/file?query to /dir/file.php?query
RewriteRule ^([\w\/-]+)(\?.*)?$ $1.php$2 [L,T=application/x-httpd-php]
```

The main part of the website works fine. But when I try to load the blog, I must add a trailing slash at the end of the URL to make it work.

http://www.example.com/blog >> 403 Forbidden error

http://www.example.com/blog/ >> Loads correctly

I tried to add trailing slash after URLs using htaccess, But I dont know is this the best solution or not? Could anyone suggest a way to ignore blog folder to be effected by beautiful url?

Comment: Any reason you didn't use Wordpress to develop the whole site?

Comment: The main part of the website is more graphical, and it is not easy to implement with Wordpress.

Comment: I asked because Wordpress is set up to deliver the `beautiful` URLs.  You could add a RewriteRule specifically for your blogs address.  Also, it's not hard to deliver a "graphical" website with Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

I simple way to handle this is to create a file called blog.php which simply redirects to example.com/blog/.

Comment: It think it is because of the blog folder that makes blog.php not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog
```

above the RewriteRules.

Not tested it, I think it should work

Comment: I have searched this solution already, But I get the same error, I dont know why? error: Forbidden, You don't have permission to access /blog on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.